# Python : easy way to do geometric mean in python?

Tags: python, math, statistics, geometric-mean

I wonder is there any easy way to do geometric mean using python but without using python package. If there is not, is there any simple package to do geometric mean?

Comment: Well [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/026cae6801f672b9858d55935ec7397183dc3a36) is the formula. What is not clear about it?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gmean.html#scipy.stats.gmean

Comment: If you are willing to use `numpy`, use `np.exp(np.mean(np.log(R)))`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The formula of the gemetric mean is:

[image: geometrical mean]

So you can easily write an algorithm like:

```
import numpy as np

def geo_mean(iterable):
    a = np.array(iterable)
    return a.prod()**(1.0/len(a))
```

You do not have to use numpy for that, but it tends to perform operations on arrays faster than Python.  See [this answer for why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385745/34935).

In case the chances of *overflow* are high, you can map the numbers to a *log* domain first, calculate the sum of these logs, then multiply by 1/n and finally calculate the exponent, like:

```
import numpy as np

def geo_mean_overflow(iterable):
    return np.exp(np.log(iterable).mean())
```

Comment: Good job with using logs for this.  People often forget about overflow.

Comment: What actually is overflow ?

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra: a floating point has a fixed number of bits. Hence it can represent a fixed number of values. Overflow is a sitation in which you calculate a number that can no longer be represented. Python uses a 64-bit float, so that means the maximum value is 1.7976931348623157e+308. Although this is rather large, in case we do not work with logs, and we have for example 310 numbers that each are around 10, then overflow can already occur.

Comment: @BhabaniMohapatra: see for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082459/what-is-overflow-and-underflow-in-floating-point (this is indeed more specific to JavaScript, but this phenomena happen in all programming languages with floating points).

Comment: Can you comment on the difference between ``a.sum()`` and ``sum(a)`` as it relates to efficiency or overlow? and why not write ``np.exp(a.mean())`` (last line)? Thanks.

Comment: `a.sum()` will perform a sum in *numpy* sum, which is faster than a sum in Python over iterables). As for the mean, if you do this with numpy, you get a NaN, where by using `len(a)` this will raise a `division by 0`, personally I prefer tha latter, but this is of course more a matter of "taste".

Comment: If the array contains negative numbers then you can do the following
`n = len(a)`, `m = len(a[a<0])`, `logs = np.log(np.abs(a))`, `return np.exp(np.mean(logs)) * ((-1)**m)**(1/n)`. This can return a complex number.

Answer (score 42):

In case someone is looking here for a library implementation, there is [gmean()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gmean.html) in scipy, possibly faster and numerically more stable than a custom implementation:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import gmean
>>> gmean([1.0, 0.00001, 10000000000.])
46.415888336127786
```

Compatible with both Python 2 and 3.*

Answer (score 41):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library comes with the [`geometric_mean`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.geometric_mean) function  as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module:

```
from statistics import geometric_mean

geometric_mean([1.0, 0.00001, 10000000000.]) # 46.415888336127786
```

Comment: Nice - this will work on any Python >= 3.8, including systems where it is not possible/practical to install other packages like numpy.

Answer (score 5):

just do this:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10]


print reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, numbers)**(1.0/len(numbers))
```

Comment: Now it is correct. Note however that by using `reduce(..)` you will introduce some computational overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an overflow-resistant version in pure Python, basically the same as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099751/3694).

```py
import math

def geomean(xs):
    return math.exp(math.fsum(math.log(x) for x in xs) / len(xs))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also calculate the geometrical mean with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.exp(np.mean(np.log([1, 2, 3])))
```

result:

```
1.8171205928321397
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use pow function, as follows :

```
def p(*args):
    k=1
    for i in args:
        k*=i
    return pow(k, 1/len(args))]

>>> p(2,3)
2.449489742783178
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Geometric mean

```py
import pandas as pd
geomean=Variable.product()**(1/len(Variable))
print(geomean)
```

###### Geometric mean with Scipy

```py
from scipy import stats
print(stats.gmean(Variable))
```