# Python: geometric mean a**1/n if a too large

Tags: python

i have large list of values:

```
[23.22, 50.44 .... 32.53]
```

after i should get next value:

```
reduce(operator.mul, [Decimal(i) for i in list])
```

print value - `4.248649022193430909459625077E+583` this value is too large
but i have next action:

```
value**1/len(list)
```

I can not get the value if the list is very large - Is it possible to get the geometric mean in that case?

Comment: `value**1` is `value`, so `value**1/len(list)` is just `value/len(list)`. That is probably not what you meant to write, but that is what you have written.

Comment: @khelwood no)))

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099751/107660

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of *multiplication* of the items, *sum* their *logarithms*:

```
geometric_mean = (a1 * ... * an) ** (1/n) =
               = exp((log(a1) + .. + log(an)) / n)
```